# How to get substring index based on runes not bytes in Go?

Tags: string, go, unicode, substr

I'm playing with Golang and found this problem. I can use the following code to get the index based on bytes:

```
strings.Index("您好你好", "你好")
```

What I got is 6 and it's based on bytes counting.

If we count on runes (characters), we should get 2 which is what I want. How can I get what I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`utf8.RuneCountInString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#RuneCountInString) method:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
    input_string := "您好你好"
    byte_index := strings.Index(input_string, "你好")
    fmt.Println(utf8.RuneCountInString(input_string[:byte_index]))
}
```